# How do I check to see if an Identity role exists before it is created?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-roles

In my application I am creating Identity Roles but want to make sure that one of the same name does not exist. Here is what I have tried

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var Role = new IdentityRole();
    return View(Role);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(IdentityRole Role)
{
    var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(_context);
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
    if (!roleManager.RoleExists(Role.ToString()))
    {
        _context.Roles.Add(Role);
        _context.SaveChanges(); //error points here
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["message"] = "This role already exists. Please check your roles and try again";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

}
```

I know it errors out because it is a duplicate, since it works when the `Role` is different, but why does it seem not use the if/else clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are not passing the role name into the `Exists` function, you are passing `Role.ToString()` which resolves to the name of the class, probably something like `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole`. Instead you should be passing `Role.Name`, like this:

```
if (!roleManager.RoleExists(Role.Name))
{
    _context.Roles.Add(Role);
    _context.SaveChanges(); //error points here
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```